# SSL configuration on Tomcat 7 using CA certificate :The security certificate was not issued by a trusted certificate authority

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, tomcat7, thawte

Step by step process that I have followed to generate privatekey(keystore) then CSR and then importing Thawate Certificate to keystore

**Step 1 :** to Generate private and java keystore (JKS)

```
keytool -genkey -keysize 2048 -alias par_private_certificate -keyalg RSA -keystore primary_asset_rigester_tomcat_live.jks -validity 730
```

**Step 2: To Generate CSR (from above generated private key )**

```
keytool -certreq -alias par_private_certificate -file primary_asset_register.csr -keystore primary_asset_rigester_tomcat_live.jks
```

**Step 3: Saved thawate certificate in notepad and saved it as “signed_certificate.p7b”**

**Step 4: Imported THwate certificate to key store (same key store where we have private key – refer Step 1)**

```
keytool -import -alias signed_cert -trustcacerts -file signed_certificate.p7b -keystore primary_asset_rigester_tomcat_live.jks
```

**Step 5: updated Tomcat server.xml file as below (To enable and configure ssl) , here I used same keystore where I have imported Thwate CA certificate and our private key**

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
 keystoreFile="/export/home/parsupport/Tomcat_certs/latest_certificate/primary_asset_rigester_tomcat_live.jks" keystorePass="par_live" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

**Step 6:** Started tomcat and tried to launch application , Tomcat started successfully but when I try to launch application Browser give me security warning as below .
     “ The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.”
Seems like browser teat this certificate as a self-signed certificate , but that is not the case as we are using Thwate certificate and even “common name” used in CSR is same as our application domain name (URL)